# Does VB.Net's lack of implicit interfaces make what I'm trying to do impossible?

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, interface, implicit

I know VB.Net does not allow implicit interface implementation like C#. And thus code like the following has no direct VB.Net correlation:

```
public interface IBackgroundWorkerAdapter
{
    bool IsBusy { get; set; }
    bool WorkerReportsProgress { get; set; }
    bool WorkerSupportsCancellation { get; set; }
    event DoWorkEventHandler DoWork;
    event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChanged;
    event RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler RunWorkerCompleted;
    void RunWorkerAsync();
    void CancelAsync();
    void ReportProgress(int progressPercent);
    void ReportProgress(int progressPercent, object userState);
}

public class BackgroundWorkerAdapter: BackgroundWorker, IBackgroundWorkerAdapter
{

}
```

So the closest think I could think of in VB.Net is to do the following using the `Shadows` keyword (since none of the operations are virtual):

```
Public Class BackgroundWorkerAdapter
    Inherits BackgroundWorker
    Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter

    Public Shadows ReadOnly Property IsBusy As Boolean _
        Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.IsBusy
        Get
            Return MyBase.IsBusy
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shadows Property WorkerReportsProgress As Boolean _
        Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.WorkerReportsProgress
        Get
            Return MyBase.WorkerReportsProgress
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            MyBase.WorkerReportsProgress = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shadows Property WorkerSupportsCancellation As Boolean _
        Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.WorkerSupportsCancellation
        Get
            Return MyBase.WorkerSupportsCancellation
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            MyBase.WorkerSupportsCancellation = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shadows Event DoWork(
                ByVal sender As Object,
                ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.DoWork

    Public Shadows Event ProgressChanged(
                ByVal sender As Object,
                ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.ProgressChanged

    Public Shadows Event RunWorkerCompleted(
                ByVal sender As Object,
                ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.RunWorkerCompleted

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub CancelAsync() _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.CancelAsync
        MyBase.CancelAsync()
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub ReportProgress(ByVal progressPercent As Integer) _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.ReportProgress
        MyBase.ReportProgress(progressPercent)
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub ReportProgress(
                ByVal progressPercent As Integer,
                ByVal userState As Object) _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.ReportProgress
        MyBase.ReportProgress(progressPercent, userState)
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub RunWorkerAsync() _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.RunWorkerAsync
        MyBase.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then I'm trying to use the wrapper as follows:

```
Private ReadOnly _Worker As IBackgroundWorkerAdapter
Public ReadOnly Property Worker() As IBackgroundWorkerAdapter
    Get
        Return _Worker
    End Get
End Property

...

AddHandler Me.Worker.DoWork,
    Sub()
        ...
    End Sub

AddHandler Me.Worker.ProgressChanged,
    Sub(sender, e)
        Dim args = DirectCast(e, ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        ...
    End Sub

AddHandler Me.Worker.RunWorkerCompleted,
    Sub()
        ...
    End Sub

Me.Worker.RunWorkerAsync()
```

Yet, of course this doesn't work (the event handler's are not executing), likely because I'm calling the base class for the `RunWorkerAsync` and `ReportProgress` methods, and the base class isn't using the Shadowed events. **Thus, is there any way to achieve the same end result where the `BackgroundWorker` implements an interface like in C#, but instead using explicit interface implementation for VB.Net?**

---

### UPDATE With Full Solution <sub><sup>(Using Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer)</sup></sub>

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class BackgroundWorkerAdapter
    Inherits BackgroundWorker
    Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter

    Public Shadows ReadOnly Property IsBusy As Boolean _
        Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.IsBusy
        Get
            Return MyBase.IsBusy
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shadows Property WorkerReportsProgress As Boolean _
        Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.WorkerReportsProgress
        Get
            Return MyBase.WorkerReportsProgress
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            MyBase.WorkerReportsProgress = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shadows Property WorkerSupportsCancellation As Boolean _
        Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.WorkerSupportsCancellation
        Get
            Return MyBase.WorkerSupportsCancellation
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            MyBase.WorkerSupportsCancellation = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shadows Custom Event DoWork As DoWorkEventHandler _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.DoWork

        AddHandler(ByVal value As DoWorkEventHandler)
            AddHandler MyBase.DoWork, value
        End AddHandler

        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As DoWorkEventHandler)
            RemoveHandler MyBase.DoWork, value
        End RemoveHandler

        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnDoWork(e)
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event

    Public Shadows Custom Event ProgressChanged As ProgressChangedEventHandler _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.ProgressChanged

        AddHandler(ByVal value As ProgressChangedEventHandler)
            AddHandler MyBase.ProgressChanged, value
        End AddHandler

        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As ProgressChangedEventHandler)
            RemoveHandler MyBase.ProgressChanged, value
        End RemoveHandler

        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnProgressChanged(e)
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event

    Public Shadows Custom Event RunWorkerCompleted As RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.RunWorkerCompleted

        AddHandler(ByVal value As RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler)
            AddHandler MyBase.RunWorkerCompleted, value
        End AddHandler

        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler)
            RemoveHandler MyBase.RunWorkerCompleted, value
        End RemoveHandler

        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnRunWorkerCompleted(e)
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub CancelAsync() _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.CancelAsync
        MyBase.CancelAsync()
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub ReportProgress(ByVal progressPercent As Integer) _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.ReportProgress
        MyBase.ReportProgress(progressPercent)
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub ReportProgress(
                ByVal progressPercent As Integer,
                ByVal userState As Object) _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.ReportProgress
        MyBase.ReportProgress(progressPercent, userState)
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub RunWorkerAsync() _
                Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.RunWorkerAsync
        MyBase.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Why the interface at all? Why even subclass? Your subclass of `BackgroundWorker` is just a wrapper and doesn't add anything useful (that you've shown). What's the purpose here? I can understand if it's just a one-off self-learning experiment.

Comment: @ Joel B Fant. I'm wanting to use dependency injection in the code, and a direct reference to the `BackgroundWorker` is a concrete dependency. Using interfaces allows one to have loosely coupled code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, as with the subs you've already shown, you need to pass all of your calls down to the same calls in the base class. The trickiest are the event handlers, but `DoWork` can be implemented as:

```vb
Public Shadows Custom Event DoWork As DoWorkEventHandler Implements IBackgroundWorkerAdapter.DoWork
    AddHandler(Value As DoWorkEventHandler)
        AddHandler MyBase.DoWork, Value
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(Value As DoWorkEventHandler)
        RemoveHandler MyBase.DoWork, Value
    End RemoveHandler
    RaiseEvent(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnDoWork(e)
    End RaiseEvent
End Event
```

And similarly for the other event handlers. In this way, event handlers added through your `DoWork` event are actually added to your base classes `DoWork` event.

Comment: +1 Damien_The_Unbeliever. In fact, I figured this just after you posted this. This will indeed work and is the right answer. Thanks for validating my own conclusion.