# How to implement the interface like this in VB.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

in C# project, i have a interface like this:

```
public interface IView
{
    event EventHandler Load;
}
```

and i implement it in a webforms's user control like this:

```
public partial class LoginUserControl : UserControl, IView
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

because the UserControl's base Control have the event call Load, i not need write any thing in the LoginUserControl.

but, in vb.net, i declare the interface like this :

```
Public Interface IView
    Event Load As EventHandler
End Interface
```

also the LoginUserControl like this:

```
Partial Public Class LoginUserControl
    Inherits UserControl
    Implements IView

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub
End Class
```

and it could not build because missing implement. but i add

```
Public Event Load As EventHandler Implements IView.Load
```

vs say, 
    conflics with base class and should declared 'Shadow'

how could i do?

**Update 12/18**

I do not want to shadows the base class event.
i just want the behavior like the c#.

for example.

i have a class :

```
class A : IView
```

then i have to implement the Load event.
but if i have a class:

```
class B : Control, IView
```

the base class Control have the same name Load, 
i don't need implement any thing in B.

**Update 12/18**

Oh, yes, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493254/does-vb-nets-lack-of-implicit-interfaces-make-what-im-trying-to-do-impossible) is the solution. but , wtxxxx, it look so ballache.
but, thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if a element is declared with the same name as an element defined in the base class. in this situation, the element in this class should Shadow the base class element.
So here you can add the **Shadows** keyword to the declaration, or change the name of the element being declared.

```
Partial Public Class LoginUserControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    Implements IView
    Public Shadows Event Load As EventHandler Implements IView.Load
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

End Class


Public Interface IView
    Event Load As EventHandler
End Interface
```

Comment: no, i dont want to shadows the base class event.look my update.

Comment: @GeminiYellow: I think VB.Net does not allow implicit interface implementation like C# and thus the same code like you explained has no direct VB.Net correlation. So the closest think i could think of in vb.net is to use the "Shadows" keyword.

Comment: thanks for your help.could you post some code for the solution? i really don't know how to write vb.net.if use Shadows, the base class Load will be hiden, right? and how to raise up both IView.Load and Control.Load event.

Comment: @GeminiYellow: Even i am not very much comfortable on vb.net. But i think you can customize this by creating some wrapper class. I can see same kind of question here on  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493254/does-vb-nets-lack-of-implicit-interfaces-make-what-im-trying-to-do-impossible)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use 'Shadows' - just change the name when implementing:

```
Private Event IView_Load As EventHandler Implements IView.Load
```

Your class still implements IView.Load and you can still use the name 'Load' when accessed via an IView instance